# Add custom field to product quote on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, quote, custom-attributes

I have added some inputs to product form, when user select parameters, they generate string with id at the hidden input. Now I need to send this id to user cart, when product added to cart, and than to order.

I has found solution extend catalog_attributes.xml and quote_item with observer. But when I add product, I didn't see in checkout.Is this a correct way?

Comment: Did you finally succeed? If so, how did you proceed?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147949)